# Connect UITextField to an existing outlet

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I'm creating an universal app with storyboarding and have connected two textfields from the iPhone storyboard to two IBOutlet properties. Now I want to connect two textfields from the iPad storyboard to the same IBOutlets by CTRL-Drag, but Xcode just want to create new ones. How do I solve this problem? Both the iphone and the iPad view controllers are from the same class.

Comment: Try dragging the other way -  from the IBOutlet (the filled circle to the left) to the `UITextView`.

Comment: check the file owner of iPad's xib

Comment: For some reason there is no circles, but the application and textfields works as it should when running with iPhone.

Comment: Thanks, bobnoble. If i renamned the textfield outlet to a name I of a textfield previously deleted, the circle didn't appear. When renaming the outlet, everything worked!